# What is wrong with this OSL shader?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, shaders, osl

I don't understand what is wrong with this shader

```
shader simple_material(
    color Diffuse_Color = color(0.6, 0.8, 0.6),
    float Noise_Factor = 0.1,
    normal Normal = N,
    output closure color BSDF = diffuse_toon(normalize(Normal),1.1,0.0)
    )
{
   color material_color = Diffuse_Color * mix(1.0, noise(P * 10.0), Noise_Factor);
   BSDF = material_color * diffuse_toon(normalize(Normal),1.1,0.0);
}
```

[image]

What I'm doing wrong and why the output is black ?

I checked and re-checked everything but still I don't think there is something obviously wrong with this .

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It seems that you missed one of the following settings:

[image]

- Diffuse color of you OSL input node
- Tick Open Shading Language in the render settings
- Set Render device to CPU (GPU can't handle script nodes)